# nodejs -- Force move a Busy Directory

Tags: node.js, fs, fs-extra

How do I move/delete/rename a busy Directory with node.js?

Currently I'm using `fs-extra` package to move and replace a directory.

```
fse.move(src, dest, { overwrite: true }, err => {
    if (err) return console.error(err)
    console.log('moved')
 })
```

`src` and `dest` have the same folder name of course, But `dest` folder is busy and I need to overwrite even if it busy or blocked.
[image]

Comment: _“`src` and `dest` have the same folder name of course”_ — Why “of course”? What are you trying to do? What are you trying to replace the directory with?

Comment: @user4642212 I need to update `dest` files which contains `node_modules` and other files. The problem is that I have no other ways to update except this, That's because I run update code after `dest` is in use (software open).